# How can I prove that if a series is Cauchy, then the absolute value between any two consecutive members is less than epsilon?

Tags: real-analysis

It is given that the sequence $(a_n)$ is Cauchy. Then I am to prove that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is N such that for all $n \geq N$ and that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $|a_n-a_{n+k}| < \epsilon$.

I am thinking that this can be done in two cases where we substitute the respective sequences with n and m because in the definition of Cauchy sequences specifies that $\epsilon > 0$ there is N such that for all $m,n \geq N$, $|a_n-a_m| < \epsilon$. The two cases I am thinking of m > n and n > m. I am just confused on how to put this into words since I want to use the $\epsilon /2$ argument. Or perhaps I can start with replacing n = n and m = 2+k? I am not sure at all.

Comment: Hint: Consider $|a_{n}-a_{n+1}|+|a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}|+....+|a_{n+k-1}-a_{n+k}|$ where each is less than $\epsilon$ by the cauchy criterion.

Comment: Am I applying the Triangle Inequality and using each difference with the $\epsilon/k$ argument?

Answer (score 2):

By definition of Cauchy, given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we can choose an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m \geq N$ we have $|a_n - a_m| < \varepsilon$. Now if $n \geq N$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $n+k$ is also greater than or equal to $N$, and so we get that the conclusion of the problem holds. You might be overthinking this.

Comment: I am just suspicious because there was a hint that we need to use the m>n and n>m cases.. so it may not be as simple as that.

Comment: I don't think that it matters if $m>n$ or if $n>m$ because $|a_n - a_m| = |a_m - a_n|$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main points I think are worth mentioning.

1. When you are in absolute value bars, $\vert a_m - a_n \vert = \vert a_n - a_m \vert$. You can see this is true by multiplying by a $\vert 1 \vert = \vert -1 \vert$ like so:

$\vert a_n - a_m \vert = \vert (1) \vert \vert a_n - a_m \vert \\ = \vert -1 \vert \vert a_n - a_m \vert \\= \vert (-1)(a_n - a_m \vert \\ = \vert a_m - a_n \vert$.

EDIT:

It seems the pedagogical point of this question is to show that you can index a sequence by taking two integers $m,n$ or by taking two integers $m, m+k$. The difference is very subtle, but it may come in handy when you need to make use of induction on $k$.

TLDR: This result follows easily via induction on $k$. In fact, induction isn't strictly necessary.

2. Secondly, let $k = 1$. Now the fact that "distance" between subsequent terms may be less than $\epsilon$ is simply a special case of a sequence that is Cauchy.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this does make sense I am just curious why we would have to use those two inequalities if it is the same anyways since it is the absolute value.

Comment: This question is subtle... I will edit my answer to highlight the pedagogical point